# What are good color coatings for a steel surface?

Tags: steel, manufacturing-engineering

I need to decide upon a color coating for a steel surface. This will be a grill top accessory and will be in contact with flames. I would prefer a black/brown coating color. I was considering teflon but what other suitable coatings are out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teflon will burn off the top of grill racks; vaporizes above about 700 F. Carbon steel will turn brown with oxides, Stainless will turn black with oxides and some of mine may be carbon from burned stuff (I have not used the "self clean" burn for awhile). I suggest an oxide ( iron ,chrome) coating. It depends on what is the temperature of "flames" , a few hundred degrees or 1200 F degrees

Comment: Tip: You can also use HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).

Comment: Great, thank you for the answer. This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Just another quick question: I was thinking of black oxide. But I read that black oxide is rubbed with oil to enhance the appearance. Will oil rubbed black oxide be a good choice for a grill top item?

Comment: Presumably oils will get on grill parts when they are used, initially cooking oils then melted fats.